# is it possible to get a parent function name from an argument function?

Tags: javascript

this is the behavior that i'm looking for:

parent(argFunction()) I want the argFunction to print "argFunction is an argument in parent function"

Can this behaviour be accomplished in javascript?

Comment: no.............

Comment: It would also be a false statement. `argFunction` is not passed as an argument to the `parent` function. You are calling `argFunction()`, and only then you are passing **the value it returned** to `parent`